# Python 2.7 selenium webdriver failing to read table contents on java site

Tags: java, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have been trying to work on webscraping a java site (new for me) but it just fails each time I attempt to read data from its main table. I know the element I am searching for is on the site, so I have no idea what is causing the element not to be found. I am able to search other ares, but for some reason I cannot read the table data (there are no elements with the same class designation, but I have included the site in the code below). Can someone help me understand what I may be missing?

***NOTE: The site requires a username/password combination, and I sign in with no problem.***

My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys, os, requests
from os import system

def main():
    file = open("wbSc2.txt","w")
    print 'starting...'
    print >> file, 'starting...'
    site2 = "https://www.oddsmonkey.com/Tools/Oddsmatcher.aspx"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    print 'grabbing site'
    print >> file, 'grabbing site'
    driver.get(site2)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    user = driver.find_element_by_id("dnn_ctr433_Login_Login_DNN_txtUsername")
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("dnn_ctr433_Login_Login_DNN_txtPassword")
    user.send_keys('myusername')
    password.send_keys('mypassword')
    submit = driver.find_element_by_id("dnn_ctr433_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin")
    submit.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    close = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='rltbActionButton rltbCloseButton']") 
    close.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    try:
        print 'attempting to find the table'
        print >> file, 'attempting to find the table'
        table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='RAD_SPLIITER_dnn_ctr956_View_RadSpliter1']")
        print 'successfully found table'
        print >> file, 'attempting table find'
        print table.text
        print >> file, table.text
    except:
        print 'failed to find table'
        print >> file, 'failed to find table'

    try:
        print 'attempting to find row'
        print >> file, 'attempting to find row'
        row = table.find_element_by_xpath('tr')
        print 'successfully found row'
        print >> file, 'successfully found row'
        print row.text
        print >> file, row.text
    except:
        print 'failed to find row'
        print >> file, 'failed to find row'
    driver.close()
    system("pause") 

main()
```

I keep failing to find the table, and I'm not sure why because it exists on the site as seen in its source code:

```
<table id="RAD_SPLITTER_dnn_ctr956_View_RadSplitter1" class="RadSplitter RadSplitter_Telerik" style="width:1px;height:1px;border-left-width:1px;border-top-width:1px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you’re not behind a firewall. I had the same issue and after I ran a print(driver.page_source) line I realized that my driver wasn’t reading the same source as I would normally be reading on a regular browser. If you’re sure you’re referencing the right xpath then it’s worth a shot to see what you’re driver is actually pulling from. 
(From one noob to another :) )

Comment: Thank you for the help! nothing seems to print when I add that line.

Comment: try add time.sleep(30) after close.click(), if this work, means the page need more time to load. FYI implicitly_wait() is to set the max search time for selenium to find element, if element not found within it, selenium will report NoSuchElement Exception,  It's not to set the page load time out.

Comment: @Chris Brocious I accepted your answer, because it drove me directly to the issue that yong just assisted as well. It was a mix of timing and printing out the page_source. The first issue was the attribute listed an 'l' and I was typing '1'. Even after that the timing was causing me to miss certain actions. Thank you both a lot! This has been driving me crazy!